# Jar does not run on command line

Tags: java, swing, jar, ide

I did search through google and various forums, (this one as well).

I have created an application, a java benchmark, and wanted to create a runnable jar file, to use the program on other machines. Unfortunately, the jar is not working, everything is done perfect with the code to make jar file, the program runs on command line. I tried tricks found on this forum to fix my jar creation, but it didn't work as well.

Strangely enough, when i compile the JavaBenchmark.java file i do not get only one file (JavaBenchmark.class), but also JavaBenchmark$1.class :O (anyone knows why?)

So I ask you to check my code if THERE might be some problems, I must say its a GUI app.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class JavaBenchmark  implements ActionListener
{
    private Frame mainWindow;
    private Button exit;
    private String dateAndTime;
    private TextArea values;
    private String stringMaxMemory;
    private String stringFreeMemory;
    private String stringTotalFreeMemory;
    private String stringAllocatedMemory;

    public JavaBenchmark(String s)
    {
        Date myDate = new Date();
        dateAndTime = String.format("%tA, %<tF", myDate);

        File[] roots = File.listRoots();

        mainWindow = new Frame(s);
        mainWindow.setSize(640,480);
        mainWindow.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){System.exit(0);}});

        String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
        String jvmversion = System.getProperty("java.jvm.version");
        String checkedJvmVersion;
        if (jvmversion == null)
        {
            checkedJvmVersion = "Java Virtual Machine version: N/A";
        }
        else
        {
            checkedJvmVersion = "Java Virtual Machine version: " + jvmversion;
        }
        String jvmname = System.getProperty("java.vm.name");
        String osname = System.getProperty("os.name");
        String osarchitecture = System.getProperty("os.arch");
        String osversion = System.getProperty("os.version");
        String processor = System.getenv("PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER");
        int processorCores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        double freeMemory = runtime.freeMemory();
        double allocatedMemory = runtime.totalMemory();
        double maxMemory = runtime.maxMemory();
        double totalFreeMemory = (freeMemory + (maxMemory - allocatedMemory));
        stringFreeMemory = String.format("%5.2f", (freeMemory)/1024/1024);
        stringAllocatedMemory = String.format("%5.2f", (allocatedMemory)/1024/1024);
        stringMaxMemory = String.format("%5.2f", (maxMemory)/1024/1024);
        stringTotalFreeMemory = String.format("%5.2f", (totalFreeMemory)/1024/1024);

        exit = new Button("Exit"); exit.addActionListener(this);
        values = new TextArea(30, 120);

    Panel exitButton = new Panel();

    exitButton.add(exit);

    mainWindow.add(values, "North");        
    mainWindow.add(exitButton);

    values.append("Your Java benchmark, as on: " + dateAndTime + "\n\n");
    values.append("Java version: " + version + "\n");
    values.append("Java Virtual machine version: " + checkedJvmVersion + "\n");
    values.append("Java Virtual Machine name: " + jvmname + "\n");
    values.append("\n");
    values.append("Operating System: " + osname + "\n" + osarchitecture + " os version: " + osversion + "\n");
    values.append("\n");
    values.append("Processor: " + processor + " (number of cores: " + processorCores + ")\n");
    values.append("\n");
    values.append("Memory info: \n");
    values.append("Maximum RAM memory for JVM:     " + stringMaxMemory + " Mb\n");
    values.append("Allocated RAM memory for JVM:     " + stringAllocatedMemory + " Mb\n");
    values.append("Free RAM memory for JVM:     " + stringFreeMemory + " Mb\n");
    values.append("Total free RAM memory for JVM:     " + stringTotalFreeMemory + " Mb\n\n\n");
    values.append("HardDrive, and VirtualDrive details:\n");
    for (File root : roots) {
          if (root.getTotalSpace() == 0)
          {
              continue;
          }
          else 
          {
              values.append("Disk: " + root.getAbsolutePath() + " space allocation:\n");
              values.append("Total space :"); 
              values.append(String.format("%5.2f", Double.valueOf(root.getTotalSpace())/1024/1024/1024));
              values.append(" Gb\n");
              values.append("Free space : ");
              values.append(String.format("%5.2f", Double.valueOf(root.getFreeSpace())/1024/1024/1024));
              values.append(" Gb\n");
              values.append("Occupied disk space : ");
              values.append(String.format("%5.2f", Double.valueOf(root.getTotalSpace() - root.getFreeSpace())/1024/1024/1024));
              values.append(" Gb\n\n");

          }
        }

    mainWindow.pack();              //Creating the window
    mainWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);         //true: position at (0,0)     false: position at center
    mainWindow.setResizable(false);         //Intuitively known commands
    mainWindow.setVisible(true);        //Intuitively known commands
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    new JavaBenchmark("Display");
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==exit) 
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It would be better if the title gave some hint of what your problem is.

Comment: What is the error you get? Does your JAR file Manifest have a `Main-Class` attribute? You get two classes because of the anonymous inner class at `mainWindow.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()`.

Comment: Please be more specific in your title.. titles like "I've tried everything.." or "This simply doesn't work" do not provide any valuable information as well as those who could help will likely ignore your question with such title.

Comment: Double clicking the jar file in Windows explorer does not execute the JAR unless the jar extension points to the Java VM.

Comment: The manifest file contains Main-Class attribute set to: JavaBenchmark . I also tried to make a runnable jar using Eclipse, but it is not working as well...

Comment: Please provide a package declaration for your class. It solves most problems!

Comment: It is not in any package, would I leave the declaration blank then?

Answer (score 1):

The `JavaBenchmark$1.class` is an anonymous class you create for `WindowAdapter` when you add a window listener.

As far as the Jar not working, you'd have to describe what you're doing to create the Jar to identify where you're going wrong. Chances are you're simply issuing the wrong command.

Comment: To create jar file: jar -cvfm manifest.mf JavaBenchmark.class the error shown when i try to run the jar is: Could not find the main class: JavaBenchmark Program will exit

Comment: Also I just found out that the program does not work on other machines, even if JDK is installed there, instead, it throws many exceptions, for many classed cannot be found

Answer (score 1):

JavaBenchmark$1.class is the anonymous class defined as follows:

```
new WindowAdapter(){public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){System.exit(0);}}
```